# Can I connect a 4k monitor with hdmi 1.4

Tags: hdmi, zenbook

I got a UX305C zenbook from Asus a few months ago. I was talked out of the UX390 Zenbook3 which has USB-C

I'd like to get huge external monitor and have my eye on a [40 inch 4k monitor 3840 x 2160](https://www.monitorstore.be/product/754459/category-241689/philips-brilliance-bdm4037uw.html)

It appears the UX305 has hdmi 1.4 (They never quote geeky stuff like that in the specs) which can run 4k with a refresh rate of 24Hz. Is 24Hz ok. I'm assuming the monitor won't flicker, just update only 24 times per second while probably scanning 60 times per second?

If I watched a movie or played a game I could imagine 24 Hz causing problems. But only looking at text in an editor, browser without videos, or other non video applications. Will these be a satisfactory experience with such a low refresh rate?

Comment: Gaming at 4k is... tricky. I think I can test the HDMI 1.4 performance in the morning

Comment: Not gaming or videos. Notepad++, word, excel, cygwin, skype. Or of course native unix except my HD is too small.

Answer (score 1):

It wont flicker I do not assume but the only issue I see is that if it is to be used for gaming purposes then the monitor will only run games at 24-fps even if the game is running at 60-fps so it will look almost like a slide show.  I realize that you are using it for "text in an editor, browser without videos" but it will still cause noticeable latency if you are a fast typer.  Also why on earth do you need a 4k monitor for text editor and a web browser?

Comment: I'm a programmer. There's no such thing as too many lines on the screen. Then you need 2 or 3 shells or cygwins. email program, skype. It's not hard to fill up a screen. At work I have 2 1920x1080 screen and they're always full. Just to reiterate. I'm not a gamer. Obviously movies might be nice, but are not the primary use for this monitor.

Comment: I can't imagine myself being such a fast typist I'd be unhappy with 24 fps. Not worried about that latency.

Comment: Well if you are not going to use it for movies or any like enjoyable video watching then it is fine...It can be used for videos although you may notice some latency if any at all...so yes it will work with hdmi 1.4 but to the second part of my question why the hell do you need a 4k monitor for any of those text editor programs

Comment: Well at the moment I have notepad++ taking up my left 1920, cygwin showing a find/grep on my right 1920, covered by the optical port protocol.

Comment: I have the browser were I'm writing this on my notebook screen, and Email, Keil IDE, skype, and 2 terminal emulators aren't even visible. I could fill 2x4k monitors I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a 4k tv and tried it with an 1.4 hdmi cable. Works fine, but you will not want to play a game. Even for text editing, I guess you will notice the slower refresh rate.
You can always look into a usb adapter, but I don't find one easily which is hdmi 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have a beebox plugged into a 4k60 capable screen - the beebox is a brasswell N3150 which can do 4k30 (I don't think it drops down to 24) with no issues over HDMI 1.4, and for most purposes its good enough.

For most part, I don't notice any obvious flickering or issues in normal use.

Comment: I watched Sheldon propose to amy on this matter. Maybe it's my imagination but I feel the frame rate seems a little slow, but slow movies like big Bang are highly watchable. It is a truly awesome monitor